# Run closure on main thread

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, closures

I created a class than makes implementing a picker view easier for the developer. In the UIPickerView Datasource methods, I'm returning the values from a closure. Example:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return pickerNumberOfRows!(component: component)
}
```

I am using the same thing for all datasource methods. When I run the app, it shows the picker on screen with no data. The problem is I'm receiving data from the closure which in turn are not running on the main thread.

Is there a way to run that closure on the main thread and make sure it returns a value suitable for the datasource function return value type? (ex, from the example above, the closure will return an Int)

**EDIT:**

I'm aware of using dispatch_async. However, in my case it will not help me. Let's say I created a function that runs the closure on the main thread and needs to return the value it will look something like this:

```
func closureOnMainThread()->Int{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        // Run your code here
        return self.pickerNumberOfRows!(component: 0)
    }
    return 0
}
```

However, There is a problem in the function above which is returning 0 before return the value inside the dispatch block.

**Edit 2:**
To make things clear. My code contains a custom class for the picker and a UIViewController implementing it:

```
class CustomPickerView: NSObject, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

        var pickerNumberOfRows: ((component: Int)->Int)?

        //MARK: UIPickerViewDatasource Methods
        func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
            return pickerNumberOfRows!(component: component)
        }

        func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
            return pickerNumberOfComponents!()
        }

        func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {print("Hello")
            return pickerRowTitle!(forRow: row, inComponent: component)
        }

        //MARK: UIPickerViewDelegate Methods
        func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
            pickerDidSelect!(row: row, component: component)
        }
    }
```

**UIViewController (View Did Load):**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let picker = CustomPickerView(parent: self)

        picker.pickerNumberOfRows = { component in
            return 10
        }
    }
```

Please note I removed allot of accessory functions in between so that you focus on the main code part.

The developer can pass in the logic he wants in variables of closures.

Comment: You can use `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {//Do your stuff}` to get the main thread inside the closure. You can decide to put all the closure code in it, or just when you finished some stuff before.

Comment: Please note that the return self.pickerNumberOfRows!(component: 0) command won't automatically make that value return in the closureOnMainThread, but just for the dispatch_async closure (and no-one reads that returned value in your example). My suggestion: use Semaphores ( https://www.raywenderlich.com/79150/grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-swift-part-2 ).

Comment: you cannot put `dispatch_async` in `closureOnMainThread` like that. It is a async process so it will return 0 defined outside of GCD block. SO there must be some issue inside closure code. Post that too.

Comment: @RJE I'm aware that it doesn't work above, the closure for the example above just returns an Int (example, 10) there is no extra code inside of it.

Comment: I think you are mixing up multi-threading and synchronous/asynchronous behaviour in your question. You can have asynchronous behaviour within a single thread. A picker view typically does not need any multi-threading, unless it would take a very long time to find out what data to show in the picker view. So, you can simply call the closures from the UIPickerViewDelegate methods, and you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Hope I undestand currently. In this block you can run any code, and it will execute on the main Thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { 
            // Run your code here
        }
```

You can run this to know if you are on main thread or not:

```
NSThread.isMainThread()
```

## EDIT

What you are looking for is, insted of returning a sync response :
->Int

You should return a block, async response:

```
func someLongProcessTaskAndReturnCompenents(completion: (components: Int)->Void){

    //Here you can do your long process task on back thread...
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

                        completion(self.pickerNumberOfRows!(component: 0))
                    }
         }
```

Now when you run it, the response will return synchronized:

```
someLongProcessTaskAndReturnCompenents { (components) in
            //Your logic after response
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies. In case I'm going to use your method, how are you going to handle calling someLongProcessTaskAndReturnCompenents in the picker view datasource method?

Comment: All the code you have pasted is running on the main thread. If you would like a specific answer for you case, show in your question were exactly are you dealing with that kind of task. Is the data your displaying is coming from server?

Comment: I'm still testing the code so the data is static. Isn't closures suavely run on another thread when you run them? Sometimes when i run the app and delay it's lunch through  breakpoint, the data appear and then start disappearing while scrolling through them. I guess the main problem in the way i'm reading the data from closures. That's why I raised the issue of running them on the main thread.

Comment: There is no problem with accessin closers on diffrent threads. And they will execute on the tread you started them on, at your example, on the main thread. If this is what you asked for, please accept my answer.

Comment: Outdated Swift code. Here is current one: `DispatchQueue.main.async() {}`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put *dispatch_async* in *closureOnMainThread* like that. It is a async process so it will return 0 defined outside of GCD block. SO there must be some issue inside closure code.

Its has to be synchronouse not asynchronous.

So try some this like this. - This is just a sample code block only.
Assuming *pickerNumberOfRows* will return a Int on same thread.(I used *dispatch_sync* instead of *dispatch_async*)

```
func closureOnMainThread()->Int{
    var x = 0;
    if (NSThread.isMainThread() == true) {
        x = self.pickerNumberOfRows!(component: 0) 
    } else {
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            x = self.pickerNumberOfRows!(component: 0)
        }
    }
    return x
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Okay, the problem was not even related to threading/closures. The problem was in using ***let*** or ***var*** in the view controller where I instantiating the custom picker. Here is a new view controller implementation:

```
var picker: HBPickerView?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    picker = HBPickerView(parent: self)

    picker!.presentPicker()
}
```

Thanks for everyone who shared their answers.

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with your original question.

Comment: @MCMatan well that was my solution to the problem.